# Tracing across microservices using SpringBoot 3, Kafka, Otel, Micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, trace, micrometer

We are upgrading several microservices to SpringBoot 3. As a part of this upgrade, we move from Spring Sleuth to Micrometer for handling the tracing. The microservices communicate using Kafka.

The problem is the following:

Within microservice A, a TraceId as well as a SpanId is created and logged. As a last step, service A writes some data to Kafka. Those messages have the headers `traceparent` `X_INSTANA_C` `X_INSTANA_L` `X_INSTANA_L_S` `X_INSTANA_S` and `X_INSTANA_T` (the `traceparent` contains the TraceId which has also been logged). But microservice B which then consumes this messages does not use the provided TraceId (there is no TraceId set at all). I would have expected that when consuming the Kafka messages, the according `traceparent` is used to set the TraceId.

Some more information about the setup:

There is a common configuration for all the microservices. Within this common config, the `pom.xml` contains the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-otlp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the tracing config:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:tracing-settings.properties")
public class CommonTracingConfig {

  @Bean
  OtlpHttpSpanExporter otlpHttpSpanExporter(@Value("${management.otel.tracing.endpoint}") final String uri) {
    return OtlpHttpSpanExporter.builder()
      .setEndpoint(uri)
      .setCompression("gzip")
      .build();
  }

  @Bean
  ObservedAspect observedAspect(final ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
    return new ObservedAspect(observationRegistry);
  }
}
```

And the `tracing-settings.properties`:

```
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
management.tracing.propagation.type=W3C
management.otel.tracing.endpoint=http://${INSTANA_AGENT_HOST:localhost}:4318/v1/traces
management.otlp.metrics.export.resource-attributes.service.name=${spring.application.name}-${STAGE:local}
```

Each of the microservices uses the following common Kafka configuration :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@PropertySource("classpath:kafka-settings.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:kafka-settings-${STAGE:local}.properties")
public class CommonKafkaConfig {

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate(final ProducerFactory<?, ?> producerFactory) {
    final KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    kafkaTemplate.setObservationEnabled(true);
    return kafkaTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object>> kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory(final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                                                                              final ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory,
                                                                                                                              final KafkaBatchRetrier kafkaBatchRetrier) {
    final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = createKafkaListenerContainerFactory(configurer, consumerFactory);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setBatchInterceptor((records, consumer) -> BatchRecordCompactor.compactRecords(records));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAdviceChain(kafkaBatchRetrier);
    return factory;
  }

  private ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> createKafkaListenerContainerFactory(final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                                                      final ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory) {
    final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, consumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(null);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setObservationEnabled(true);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

In the `application.yml` the logging is formatted as follows:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: timestamp=%d thread=%t loglevel=%-5p class=%c appname=@artifactId@ traceid=%X{traceId:-} spanid=%X{spanId:-} message="%m"%n
```

In microservice A we start a new trace by using `@Observed()` which then results in a traceId as well as spanId being logged. As expected, the traceid is also set as `traceparent` header in the Kafka message.

I would then expect that microservice B consumes a message and uses the `traceparent` header as the according traceId. But in microservice B, there is neither a traceId nor a spanId logged upon consuming a message from Kafka.

Does anybody have an idea what could be missing?

Comment: We have found a solution.
The problem in our code is, that the KafkaListener used is a BatchListener. As a BatchListener can possibly consume messages with several different TraceIds, it has no idea which one is the correct one and therefore does not set any TraceId.
When using a "normal" KafkaListener, the TraceId is correctly set.